# How to train a multiple linear regression model to find the best combination of variables?

Tags: r, lm

I want to run a linear regression model with a large number of variables and I want an R function to iterate on good combinations of these variables and give me the best combination.

Answer (score 3):

The [glmulti package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=glmulti) will do this fairly effectively:

> Automated model selection and model-averaging. Provides a wrapper for glm and other functions, automatically generating all possible models (under constraints set by the user) with the specified response and explanatory variables, and finding the best models in terms of some Information Criterion (AIC, AICc or BIC). Can handle very large numbers of candidate models. Features a Genetic Algorithm to find the best models when an exhaustive screening of the candidates is not feasible.

Unsolicited advice follows:

**HOWEVER.** [image: skull][image: skull][image: skull] Please be aware that while this approach can find the model that minimizes *within-sample* error (the goodness of fit on your actual data), it has two **major** problems that should make you think twice about using it.

- this type of data-driven model selection will almost always **destroy** your ability to make reliable inferences (compute p-values, confidence intervals, etc.). See [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection).
- it may overfit your data (although using the information criteria listed in the package description will help with this)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to characterize a "best" model, but AIC is a common one, and base R offers `step()`, and package `MASS` offers `stepAIC()`.

```
summary(lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss))
slm1 <- step(lm1)
summary(slm1)
slm1$anova
```